# html javascript collapse accordion

Tags: javascript, html, css

i have an accordion inside of a side navigation window. If I open all the panels they stay open if i close the side navigation panel. I want my accordion to collapse when my side navigation closes.
my code is attached.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {
    font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}

.sidenav {
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #111;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
    padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidenav a {
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #818181;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.sidenav a:hover, .offcanvas a:focus{
    color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sidenav .closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 25px;
    font-size: 36px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

#main {
    transition: margin-left .5s;
    padding: 16px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
  .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
}
button.accordion {
    background-color: #eee;
    color: #444;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 18px;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    text-align: left;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    transition: 0.4s;
}

button.accordion.active, button.accordion:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}

button.accordion:after {
    content: '\002B';
    color: #777;
    font-weight: bold;
    float: right;
    margin-left: 5px;
}

button.accordion.active:after {
    content: "\2212";
}

div.panel {
    padding: 0 18px;
    background-color: white;
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
  <button class="accordion">Section 1</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Section 2</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Section 3</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>
</div>

<div id="main">
 
  <span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; open</span>
</div>

<script>
function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
}

function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft= "0";
}

var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].onclick = function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.maxHeight){
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    } 
  }
}
</script>
     
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can anybody help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a function that opens/closes panels, and in `closeNav()` just loop through the panels and close them all.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    body {
      font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
    }
    
    .sidenav {
      height: 100%;
      width: 0;
      position: fixed;
      z-index: 1;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      background-color: #111;
      overflow-x: hidden;
      transition: 0.5s;
      padding-top: 60px;
    }
    
    .sidenav a {
      padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 25px;
      color: #818181;
      display: block;
      transition: 0.3s;
    }
    
    .sidenav a:hover,
    .offcanvas a:focus {
      color: #f1f1f1;
    }
    
    .sidenav .closebtn {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      right: 25px;
      font-size: 36px;
      margin-left: 50px;
    }
    
    #main {
      transition: margin-left .5s;
      padding: 16px;
    }
    
    @media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
      .sidenav {
        padding-top: 15px;
      }
      .sidenav a {
        font-size: 18px;
      }
    }
    
    button.accordion {
      background-color: #eee;
      color: #444;
      cursor: pointer;
      padding: 18px;
      width: 100%;
      border: none;
      text-align: left;
      outline: none;
      font-size: 15px;
      transition: 0.4s;
    }
    
    button.accordion.active,
    button.accordion:hover {
      background-color: #ddd;
    }
    
    button.accordion:after {
      content: '\002B';
      color: #777;
      font-weight: bold;
      float: right;
      margin-left: 5px;
    }
    
    button.accordion.active:after {
      content: "\2212";
    }
    
    div.panel {
      padding: 0 18px;
      background-color: white;
      max-height: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
      transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
    <button class="accordion">Section 1</button>
    <div class="panel">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>

    <button class="accordion">Section 2</button>
    <div class="panel">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>

    <button class="accordion">Section 3</button>
    <div class="panel">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="main">

    <span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; open</span>
  </div>

  <script>
    
    var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
    var i;
    
    function openNav() {
      document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
      document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
    }
    
    function closeNav() {
      document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
      document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "0";
      for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
        closePanel(acc[i]);
      }
    }
    
    function openPanel(el) {
      el.classList.add("active");
      el.nextElementSibling.style.maxHeight = el.nextElementSibling.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
    
    function closePanel(el) {
      el.classList.remove("active");
      el.nextElementSibling.style.maxHeight = null;
    }
    
    for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
      acc[i].onclick = function() {
        if (this.classList.contains("active")) {
          closePanel(this);
        } else {
          openPanel(this);
        }
      };
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```